# Jquery not loaded in Firefox 10

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox

Jquery is not loaded in Firefox 10.0.5 but is loaded in IE 8. The following `alert` message in the master page works in IE but not in FF:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/jscript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("I'm here");
        });
    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Firebug shows the message `$ is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: `type="text/jscript"` ?? change it to `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: jscript and javascript are different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Not this:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I changed `"text/jscript"`, which is supported by IE but not Firefox, to `"text/javascript"`, which is supported in both IE and Firefox.